# Querying a task's Result property cause the thread pool to create a new thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Here is a quote from Jeffrey Richter's "CLR via C#" book:

> ** Starting a New Task Automatically When Another Task Completes**
>
> ...calling Wait or querying a task’s
>   Result property when the task has not
>   yet finished running will most likely
>   cause the thread pool to create a new
>   thread, which increases resource usage
>   and hurts scalability.

Why does the thread pool need to create a new thread?

Comment: Personally I expect `Wait` to be a common operation - and I would be surprised if that involved an additional thread.

Comment: @Marc Gravell

And the Reflector says that you're right:

'code'
public TResult get_Result()
{
    if (!base.IsCompleted)
    {
        Debugger.NotifyOfCrossThreadDependency();
        base.Wait();
    }
    base.ThrowIfExceptional(!this.m_resultWasSet);
    return this.m_result;
}
'code'

Comment: I'm reading that book as well, and I was reading the same part yesterday... but I gave up because I was very sleepy and I thought I was not getting it because of that. Now I see I'm not the only one haha

Answer (score 0):

In native code, you would first create a work item with [CreateThreadpoolWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then wait for it using the [WaitForThreadpoolWorkCallbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

In the .NET world, I would use instead the TPL, create a task, and then a [continuation task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612.aspx). Combining that with the TPL [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx) should give you the desired effect.